# tab bar View Controller view is blank

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UI tab bar application and one of the views is blank. to be specific, the view has the background set which i have set via

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Add Details";

    UIColor *backg=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"bgcamo.png"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor=backg;
}
return self;
```

}
however none of the textfields or label are displayed.

I have been to the attributes inspector for the xib in question and the custom class is set to "detailsViewController" (I know it should be a capital this was the first app I wrote) and all the connections are made

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re setting up your view controller from a XIB, then it’s probably getting `-initWithCoder:` rather than `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. Regardless, as a rule, you should do view setup like that in `-viewDidLoad` instead of in the initializer.

Comment: is that going to be making it go blank?

Comment: If you’ve put your setup code in a method that’s not being called, then that setup code will not happen.